# Overwrite web.config setting

Tags: asp.net, cache-control

Environment: IIS 7, .Net 4.0

In web.config of our application, it has this section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <add name="cache-control" value="no-cache" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Most of our application requires no-cache, but there is only one page that requires cache-control to be Private. Is a way to do it?

Appreciated for any input

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply or override settings from `web.config` to a particular page, however you can do this for all pages inside a folder, by following settings.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <remove name="cache-control" />
     <add name="cache-control" value="no-cache" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

However, you can override the `cache-control` settings in `Page_Load` event of a particular page.

```
Response.CacheControl = "Private";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change response caching for a page by setting the location attribute of `@outputcache` directive.

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="Server" %>
```